# How to run redis server and juggernaut server in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, production-environment, juggernaut

I am using [juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) push server. How to start redis and juggernaut in production mode cause I

```
 juggernaut
```

or

```
redis-server will keep on showing me log etc.
```

I am using ruby on rails 3.

**EDIT**

I followed these two guides to setup [juggernaut](https://gist.github.com/1055322) and [redis](http://www.denofubiquity.com/nosql/412/) on production server

[image: Terminal commands.]

Seems like both the servers are running smooth now. But how can i access

```
     :8080/application.js for juggernaut.
```

I tried

```
   my_ip:8080/application.js but nothing.
```

For hosting I am using Linode.

**EDIT2**

When I am trying to stop/start redis server its gives me output ie:

```
  Starting/Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
```

But nothing when i m doing the same for juggernaut. Check screenshot.

[image]

**EDIT**

I can't see any log for juggernaut.. There is one for redis but nothin for juggernaut

[image]

**EDIT**

1. Executable file permissions to /etc/init.d/juggernaut file -- YES

   ```
       -rwxr-xr-x 1 fizzy fizzy 1310 Sep 19 11:06 juggernaut
   ```
2. PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid' is defined. Does that exist? --- NO
3. In the 'start' part it runs 'chown juggernaut:juggernaut'. Does the user juggernaut exist and is it member of the group juggernaut?  -- YES/YES

   ```
     cat /etc/group
         redis:x:1002:
         juggernaut:x:113:

     groups juggernaut
         juggernaut : juggernaut
   ```

**EDIT**

```
     fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/bin/juggernaut 
              ls: cannot access /usr/bin/juggernaut: No such file or directory
     fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/juggernaut 
            lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Sep 20 02:48 /usr/local/bin/juggernaut -> ../lib/node_modules/juggernaut/server.js
```

I tried changing

```
        DAEMON=/usr/bin/juggernaut
```

to

```
        DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/juggernaut
```

after that i tried restarting the juggernaut using

```
         sudo /etc/init.d/juggernaut start
```

Server started but not as background process/service.

**EDIT**

Running script in debugging mode ie 
changing the shebang line at the top to add an -x, eg

```
    #! /bin/bash -x
```

Here is the output:-

```
   + PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   + DAEMON=/usr/bin/juggernaut
   + NAME=Juggernaut2
   + DESC=Juggernaut2
   + PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid
   + test -x /usr/bin/juggernaut
   + exit 0
```

**EDIT**

Changing path of my juggernaut as it seems my juggernaut is installed somewhere else. Now here is the output

```
    fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/juggernaut start
    + PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    + DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/juggernaut
    + NAME=Juggernaut2
    + DESC=Juggernaut2
    + PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid
    + test -x /usr/local/bin/juggernaut
    + set -e
    + case "$1" in
    + echo -n 'Starting Juggernaut2: '
    Starting Juggernaut2: + touch /var/run/juggernaut.pid
    + chown juggernaut:juggernaut /var/run/juggernaut.pid
    + start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile /var/run/juggernaut.pid --chuid juggernaut:juggernaut --exec /usr/local/bin/juggernaut
    20 Sep 06:41:16 - Your node instance does not have root privileges. This means that the flash XML policy file will be served inline instead of on port 843. This will slow down initial connections slightly.
    20 Sep 06:41:16 - socket.io ready - accepting connections

    node.js:134
            throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
            ^
    Error: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use
        at Server._doListen (net.js:1106:5)
        at net.js:1077:14
        at Object.lookup (dns.js:153:45)
        at Server.listen (net.js:1071:20)
        at Object.listen (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut/lib/juggernaut/server.js:51:21)
        at Object.listen (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut/lib/juggernaut/index.js:9:10)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut/server.js:21:12)
        at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    + echo failed
    failed
    + exit 0
```

Comment: You have to start the service. Juggernaut is not running, you only see the 'grep' command back in your search. Will append to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to start Juggernaut and Redis as a service / background process. Starting it as a service gives the opportunity to redirect the logs to a file which you then can inspect regularly.

To create a service that automatically starts at boot time, you have to do different things based on the OS you're using:

- In Linux you can add an [init.d](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/) script ([Juggernaut Ubuntu example](https://gist.github.com/1055322), [Redis Ubuntu example](http://www.denofubiquity.com/nosql/412/))
- In Mac OS X you use [launchd](http://launchd.macosforge.org/trac/wiki).
- In Windows you use [this method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).

Make sure you start the services after creating them by adding the service to the default runlevel (will start automatically during boot time) or start them manually.

Add service to default runlevel (Linux), is also part of both the Linux tutorials above:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f juggernaut defaults
sudo update-rc.d -f redis-server defaults
```

After adding the service to the default runlevel, you still need to start the service manually (Linux):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/juggernaut start
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start
```

Comment: @Daan.. This is about Juggernaut what about redis?

Comment: I have added an Ubuntu Redis example. The idea is the same for both services.

Comment: @daan.. I have followed the both guide Check the screenshot added by me. Not able to access application.js for juggernaut server.

Comment: Have you checked the logs in /var/log ? There is probably some stale pid file lying around, or the port is in use, or a permissions issue.

Comment: I can't see any log for juggernaut.. There is one for redis but nothin for juggernaut. Check my edit in the question..

Comment: Have you made the /etc/init.d/juggernaut script executable? Try to run it without parameters. In the Juggernaut script the PID file 'PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid' is defined. Does that exist? In the 'start' part it runs 'chown juggernaut:juggernaut'. Does the user juggernaut exist and is it member of the group juggernaut?

Comment: Check my edit part now. Answers to questions are there YES/No/YES/YES

Comment: Okay, so the PID file is not created.. can you try to run each command in the Juggernaut startup script manually? Just debugging to see where it goes wrong, run it step by step. Do you get any errors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3598/discussion-between-mohit-jain-and-daan)

Comment: I am not able to figure out whats the issue. for now i m just now running it in screen. Thanks for your help. Allocating bounty to u. :)

Comment: screen or tmux is one option but then you must run the service yourself because it won't start up on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). Using [upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) did it for me.

Create a file 'juggernaut.conf' containing:

```
start on filesystem and started networking
stop on shutdown

script
    # We found $HOME is needed. Without it, we ran into problems
    export HOME="/root"

    exec /usr/local/bin/juggernaut 2>&1 >> /var/log/juggernaut.log
end script
```

Save this file in /etc/init/ (not init.d) and make it executable (chmod +x). This is it, Juggernaut runs as a deamon if the server started.

A note: next to the juggernaut.log of juggernaut itself, there is a juggernaut.log located in /var/log/upstart/ where information is written on the attempts of upstart to start juggernaut.

I more or less copy-pasted the above script from [this blog](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/12/15/run-nodejs-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-karmic/) . However, the script shown there started with:

```
 start on startup
```

This did not work for me, because the filesystem was not mounted properly at startup, so no possibility to create juggernaut.log (Read-only filesystem error). Credits to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/279594/cant-get-upstart-script-for-node-js-program-to-start-on-startup) on serverfault for solving that.